# Stripe handleServerResponse() error ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

When I call the handleServerResponse(response) from the handleSubmit method everything works just fine. But when I call it inside the own handleServerResponse function without any parameter, as it is shown in the stripe documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart) I get an error.

```
handleServerResponse(response) {
    if (response.error) {
      // Show error from server on payment form
    } else if (response.requires_action) {
      // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
      this.props.stripe
        .handleCardAction(response.payment_intent_client_secret)
        .then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // Show error in payment form
          } else {
            // The card action has been handled
            // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
            return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-charge/`, {
              method: "POST",
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                payment_intent_id: result.paymentIntent.id
              })
            })
              .then(function(confirmResult) {
                return confirmResult.json();
              }) ////Line 37, Points the error here
              .then(this.handleServerResponse);
          }
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Success");
    }
  }
```

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ card_errors: "", resp_message: "" });
    /*
    Within the context of Elements, this call to createToken knows which
    Element to tokenize, since there's only one in this group.
    */
    return this.props.stripe
      .createPaymentMethod("card", CardElement)
      .then(result => {
        if (result.error) {
          console.log("THERE IS AN ERROR IN YOUR FORM", result.error);
          return this.setState({ card_errors: result.error.message });
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Received Stripe token ---> SENDING TO SERVER: ",
            result.token
          );
          return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-charge/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id
            })
          })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(json => this.handleServerResponse(json));
        }
      });
  };
```

The error I get is the following: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleServerResponse' of undefined
    at CheckoutForm.js:37

Line 37 being inside handleServerResponse

```
.then(function(confirmResult) {
                return confirmResult.json();
              }) /// LINE 37
              .then(this.handleServerResponse);
```

I'm new to ReactJS and i don't understand why this might be happening, specially since the code is from the Stripe docs. Thought the function may be needed to be call with brackets but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Many thanks.

--EDIT: In order to fix it I had to bind this to the function as follows:

`````
            if (result.error) {
              // Show error in payment form
            } else {
              // The card action has been handled
              // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
              return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-charge/`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  payment_intent_id: result.paymentIntent.id
                })
              })
                .then(function(confirmResult) {
                  return confirmResult.json();
                })
                .then(data => this.handleServerResponse(data));
            }
          }.bind(this)````
`````

Comment: you have `this` as undefined thus the error. Try changing that to `.then(data => this.handleServerResponse(data));` see if that works,

Comment: The problem stays the same after trying that. Why is this undefined there but when I use this.handleServerResponse() in the handleSubmit() function there is not such an error?

Comment: Also tried binding this: ```this.handleServerResponse = this.handleServerResponse.bind(this);``` But the error persists

Comment: change `handleServerResponse(response) {` to an arrow function see if that resolves: `handleServerResponse = (response) => {`

Comment: Fixed it! Just had to bind(this) in a different place! I'll post the answer in the main post. Thanks @Rikin for pointing out that the error had to do with the this, I was thinking it had to do with the function not having any parameters...